# Alembic is ignoring a custom name definition for a constraint name in a migration

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a python app that relies on Postgres DB, managed using SqlAlchemy and Alembic.
One of the migration I have is as follow:

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, "avset", ["cshash"])    

def downgrade():
    op.drop_constraint(None, "avset", type_="unique")
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Because of [The importance of naming constraints](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/naming.html), I did as it says and added a convention constraint file map to the repo, which apparently works.

Moreover, I wanted to make the shown above migration reversible, without the need to flush the DB and recreate it with a new correct constraint name.

Therefore I changed the migration file as follow:

```
constraint_name = "avset_cshash_key"    
def upgrade():
        op.create_unique_constraint(
            (op.f(constraint_name)), "avset", ["cshash"]
        )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_constraint(op.f(constraint_name), "avset", type_="unique")
```

In this way
if I apply a downgrade with the old migration applied it should work because the constraint name is the same postgres gives by default.
If I apply a downgrade after an upgrade with the new migration file, it should work because I am forcing the constraint's name.

Unfortunately, this is what Alembic does if I try to create a new migration ( I would expect no changes detected)

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed unique constraint 'avset_cshash_key' on 'avset'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added unique constraint 'uq_avset_cshash' on '['cshash']'
  Generating alembic/versions/2023_12_12_0999-1f34f5585cad_test.py ...  done
```

Why is this change detected?